# '*s' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Tags: c

My stack_d.h file

```
#ifndef stack_d
#define stack_d
struct s {
    int boyut;
    int tepe;
    int dizi;
};
typedef struct s* stack;
stack * init ();
int pop(stack *);
void push (int, stack *);
void bastir(stack *);
#endif
```

My stack.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack_d.h"
stack * init(){
    stack *s = (stack *) malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->dizi =NULL;
    s->boyut =2;
    s->tepe=0;
    return s;
}
int pop(stack *s ){
        if (s->tepe <= s->boyut/4){
```

I tried this s pointer with -> but my compiler says did you mean to use ->? What should I do?

Comment: `typedef struct s* stack;` don't hide pointers behind typedefs. You are confusing yourself.

Comment: variable "stack" is not a type name If I remove typedef I get this error.

Comment: `s` is a pointer to a pointer, so accessing the structure should be like `(**s).dizi` or `(*s)->dizi`. Also don't forget to assign valid buffer for `*s` before dereferencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I do?

Remove the pointer from the `typedef`:

```
typedef struct s stack;
```

and your code should be fine. Do not use pointer `typedef`s, they are very confusing.